# Ant script javac command converted to a groovy script AntBuilder.javac

Tags: jenkins, groovy, javac, antbuilder

Hi im new in the jenkins/ant/groovy world and google couldnt help me to solve my problem.

My task is to get rid of ant scripts in the build process (with jenkins) and include them into the jenkins job (Execute system Groovy script).

The bold sections of my script are the reason for the failure, but i dont know how to solve this.

I hope someone can help me with that problem.

This is my "Execute system Groovy script":

```
antbuild = new AntBuilder()
projectHome = '...Homedirectory'

projectDomainModel = projectHome + '/CSSDomainModel'
projectPresentationBase = projectHome + '/CSSPresentationBase'
projectServices = projectHome + '/CSSServices'
projectResource = projectHome + '/src/main/resources'

Sources = projectHome + '/Presentation/JavaSource'
projectLibraries = 'lib/bin'
projectWebContent = projectHome + '/Presentation/WebContent'
projectWebInf = projectWebContent + '/WEB-INF'

deployHome = projectHome + '/target/servicekundenportal'
deployBuild = deployHome + '/build/classes'
deployWebInf = deployHome + '/WEB-INF'

foreignSources = 'src'

deployWARFile = deployHome + '/serviceportal.war'

j2eeLibraries = 'D:/Programme_x64/tomcat/8.0.21/Instanz_02/lib'
compileTarget = '1.8'

<b>compilerSourceFiles = antbuild.path{
        pathelement(path:Sources)
        pathelement(path:projectDomainModel + '/' + foreignSources)
        pathelement(path:projectPresentationBase + '/' + foreignSources)
        pathelement(path:projectServices + '/' + foreignSources)
        }

compilerLibraryFiles = antbuild.path{
        fileset(dir:projectDomainModel + '/' + projectLibraries) {include name:'**/*.jar'}
        fileset(dir:projectPresentationBase + '/' + projectLibraries) {include name:'**/*.jar'}
        fileset(dir:projectServices + '/' + projectLibraries) {include name:'**/*.jar'}
        fileset(dir:j2eeLibraries) {include name:'**/*.jar'}
        }</b>

antbuild.delete(dir:deployHome)
antbuild.delete(file:deployWARFile)
antbuild.mkdir(dir:deployBuild)

build() {   

        antbuild.javac(
            destdir:deployBuild,
            target:compileTarget,
            debug:true,
            fork:true,
            executable:'D:/Programme_x64/Java/jdk1.8.0_45/bin/javac')<b>{
                src(path:compilerSourceFiles)
                classpath(path:compilerLibraryFiles)
                }</b>
        }

build()
```

The part of the Ant script that i am not able to convert:

```
<!-- Compiler Source File Definition -->
    <path id="compilerSourceFiles">
        <pathelement path="${Sources}" />
        <pathelement path="${projectDomainModel}/${foreignSources}" />
        <pathelement path="${projectPresentationBase}/${foreignSources}" />
        <pathelement path="${projectServices}/${foreignSources}" />
    </path>

    <!-- Compiler Library Definition -->
    <path id="compilerLibraryFiles">
        <fileset id="librariesDomainModel" dir="${projectDomainModel}/${projectLibraries}">
            <include name="**/*.jar" />
        </fileset>
        <fileset id="librariesPresentationBase" dir="${projectPresentationBase}/${projectLibraries}">
            <include name="**/*.jar" />
        </fileset>
        <fileset id="librariesServices" dir="${projectServices}/${projectLibraries}">
            <include name="**/*.jar" />
        </fileset>
        <fileset dir="${j2eeLibraries}">
            <include name="**/*.jar" />
        </fileset>
    </path>



    <target name="executeCompiler" depends="preCompile">
            <javac destdir="${deployBuild}" target="${compileTarget}"
                debug="true" debuglevel="lines,vars" encoding="ISO8859-1">
                <src refid="compilerSourceFiles" />
                <classpath refid="compilerLibraryFiles" />
            </javac>
        </target>
```

Answer (score 0):

You example has a few too many dependencies on local directory structures etc to replicate in full, but using something like the below as a pattern should get you moving in the right direction:

```
def ant = new AntBuilder()

def projectHome = '...Homedirectory'

ant.path(id: 'compilerSourceFiles') {
  pathelement(path: "$projectHome/Presentation/JavaSource")
  pathelement(path: "$projectHome/CSSDomainModel/src")
  pathelement(path: "$projectHome/CSSPresentationBase/src")
  pathelement(path: "$projectHome/CSSServices/src")
}

ant.path(id: "compilerSourceFiles") {
  fileset(id: "librariesDomainModel", dir: "$projectHome/CSSDomainModel/lib/bin") {
    include(name: "**/*.jar")
  }
  fileset(id: "librariesPresentationBase", dir: "....") {
    include(name: "**/*.jar")
  }
  //...
}

ant.target(name: 'executeCompiler', depends: 'preCompile') {
  javac(destDir: "...", target: "...", debug: true, debugLevel: "lines,vars", encoding: "...") {
    src(refid: "compilerSourceFiles")
    classpath(refid: "compilerLibraryFiles")
  }
}
```

In other words, each ant xml snippet:

```
<outerelement outerattribute="outervalue"> 
    <innerelement innerattribute="innervalue" />
</outerelement>
```

gets converted to:

```
ant.outerelement(outerattribute: "outervalue") {
    innerelement(innerattribute: "innervalue")
}
```

when using AntBuilder.

Comment: my comment was too long, so i put it into an answer :). Btw, do i use the double quote " and single quote ' right?

Comment: Both quotes are valid in groovy, single if you don't need any ${} expressions in your strings, double if you do.